# Reusing overloads in other overloads

Tags: c++

If I have setter function overloads

```
void setDamageRange(const Range& r);
void setDamageRange(int min, int max);
```

and I'm able to use one of the overloads in the other

```
void Weapon::setDamageRange(const Range& r)
{
    setDamageRange(r.min, r.max);
}

void Weapon::setDamageRange(int min, int max)
{
    mDamageRange.min = min;
    mDamageRange.max = max;
}
```

should I do that? Or should I do all validity checking and assignment again like so

```
void Weapon::setDamageRange(const Range& r)
{
    mDamageRange = r;
}

void Weapon::setDamageRange(int min, int max)
{
    mDamageRange.min = min;
    mDamageRange.max = max;
}
```

?

My instincts tell me I should choose the first alternative for the purpose of reusing code, since that's generally good practice. But at the same time, it feels like it makes it messy in a way, especially if I were to provide even more function overloads, since only one of them all is the "controlling" function.

Like if I figured I didn't really need the "controlling" function and removed it, I'd have to rewrite the code for all the other overloads too.

Comment: I prefer the first one. No redundancy and improved readability :)
This is opinion based, nothing's wrong in both the approaches.

Comment: There's also third option of reusing the first overload in the second overload: `setDamageRange(Range(min, max));` and you don't have to repeat the code in `Range::operator=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should I [call one overload from the other]?

Absolutely! This is an excellent way of reusing code.

> Or should I do all validity checking and assignment again

Generally, that would go against the [*Don't Repeat Yourself*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle, because the same validations, if any, would have to go into both places.